# Xamarin forms Droid : keytool error- cannot import existing keystore after archiving app .aab

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms on MAC.

In my Mac, I'm trying to import an existing keystore that has been created in Windows 10 to publish my droid app but it gives me this error :

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <lealtd> does not exist
java.lang.Exception: Alias <lealtd> does not exist
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintEntry(Main.java:2038)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1271)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:412)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:405)
```

I have tried to open my keystore using [Keystore explore](https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) it works and I can see all the infos. I do not understand why it is not working on Xamarin

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does it contain an alias named “lealtd”?

Comment: @Jason when I open it with Keystore explore I can see lealtd in Entry Name column

Comment: @Jason When I use this command keytool -v -list -keystore .keystore I see the alias name “lealtd”

Comment: look at the logs (you might need to increase the verbosity) to see exactly what command it is using to check the keystore, and also verify it is looking at the correct file

Comment: @Jason Where Can I see please the import certificate log in Xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

I have rename my alias because there were a space and it works :

keytool -changealias -alias "lealtd " -destalias "lealtd" -keystore lealtd.keystore